# Iterations of I over J

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't understand why iterations made by i depend on the value of j I write

I have been changing the value of j for a number of different values, for example j=-6 and my code does 6 loops for each i: 111111,222222 for the range I specified

```
p = 1
for i in range(1, 3):
    j = -3
    while abs(i * j) > 0:
        p = i * j
        j = j + 1
result = p
```

The output is right, but I need to understand why the value of j affects how many iterations of why there are

Answer (score 2):

The `j` variable in no way affects your iterations of `i`, there will *always be two of those, one each for the values `1` and `2`.

What *will* change is the inner loop, the `while` one. The expression `abs(i * j)` (where `i` is either `1` or `2`) will always be positive until `j` reaches zero (counting up from some negative number.

Therefore, a `j` value of `-99` will cause more iterations of this `while` loop than a vaule of `-3`.